# Trouble using "parent" method and "this" reference to refer to the proper DOM element

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, this, parent

I'm having trouble referencing the proper html elements with the javascript "this" reference using the "parent" method.  Suppose my html is as follows:

```
<ul id="list" >
  <li id="Template" >
    <a href="#" >
      <h3 class="Name" ></h3>
    </a>
    <a class="Link" ></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Using jquery, I can dynamically create links out of the items in a list :

```
var jqXHR = $.getJSON( url, params, function(obj, status, xhr){
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
  for (var i=0; i < obj.length; i++) 
  {
    var newEntryRow = $('#Template').clone();
    newEntryRow.removeAttr('id');
    newEntryRow.data('userID', obj[i].id);
    newEntryRow.appendTo('#list');
    newEntryRow.find('.Name').text(obj[i].user_name);
    newEntryRow.find('.Link').click(function(){
      var clickedUser = $(this).parent();
      var clickedUserID = clickedUser.data('userID');
    });
  }
```

The above code will assign an "id" to each link created in the list (0, 1, 2...); however, the jquery doesn't work for the following html:

```
 <ul id="list" >
  <li id="Template" >
    <a class="Link" >
      <h3 class="Name" ></h3>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The second html snippet also creates a list of 5 "Name" links; however, the jquery assigns an "undefined" (vs. a valid ID - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4) to each of the links created in the list.  Can somebody tell me why the 2nd html snippet isn't working and how I can modify the jquery code so that the links have a valid ID assigned (instead of an "undefined")?

Thanks!

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/J6QDK/1/

Comment: mariogl - how can you tell if the links produced are have a valid ID (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) vs. an "undefined" assigned in jsfiddle?

Comment: I've added `console.log(clickedUserID)`, so I can see the values at console, and also I can see the ids in the html inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var lis = '';
    var a = [{
        "id": 1,
        "user_name": "user1",
        "user_url": "http://user1.com",
        "user_image": "http://cdn.com/user1.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_name": "user2",
        "user_url": "http://user2.com",
        "user_image": "http://cdn.com/user2.png"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "user_name": "user3",
        "user_url": "http://user3.com",
        "user_image": "http://cdn.com/user3.png"
    }];
    $.each(a, function(i, item) {
        lis += '<li id="user-' + item.id + '"><a href="' + item.user_url + '">' + '<img src="' + item.user_image + '" />' + '<h3>' + item.user_name + '</h3>' + '</a></li>';
    });
    $(lis).appendTo('#list');
    $('#list li a').on('click', function(e) {
        /* do something  */
    });
});

<ul id="list" data-role="listview"></ul>
```

Comment: aSeptik - I'm using jquery mobile to make buttons with thumbnails (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html) that direct the user to another page.  Each button is created from a list of json objects returned from an asynchronous jquery call.  Can you advise me on how to associate the jquery mobile thumbnail button with a proper ID (vs. an "undefined")?

Comment: can you provide a snip of this json object? also is useful to know from where this object is obtained?

Comment: Here's a snippet of the json object: [{"id":1,"user_name":"user1"},
{"id":2,"user_name":"user2"},{"id":3,"user_name":"user3"}] and it's returned from a webservice.  I'll edit the question to include more of the jquery code to show you.  Thanks!

Comment: The use of `live()` is not recommended. Use the new method `on()` with jQuery 1.7+, or `delegate()` if older version.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys.  I haven't had a chance to try the solution yet but it looks good so far.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the comtext of 'this' is wrong. But not sure why the first one would work and not the second because the relationship between link and the data-userId attribute would be the same?

Anyway, this might help?  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/ you can wrap the click handler so you can set the 'this' context to be whatever you want.

You could set the this context to be the new row which will have the data-userId attribute.

Hope that helps

Sam

Comment: Thanks, Sam.  The relationship between the link and data-userID attribute should be the same but for some reason, the jquery isn't working for the 2nd html snippet.  My understanding is: 1) "this" refers to the <a> element associated with class="Link", 2) the parent method refers to the <li> element.  Thus, "$(this).parent();"refers to the <li> element.  Also, "newEntryRow.data('userID', i);" refers to the userID data attribute of the <li> element, the top element of the cloned html right?  I'm new at this so please let me know what I'm misunderstanding.  Thanks!